# dynamics365 CRM populate form field with user login

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am new to dynamics 365 CRM. I created a form that the user will fill, it contains a lookup field that mapped to the User entity. I want to populate this field automatically depending on the user login. I have tried the business role but it didn't work. I have followed these links:

1. [CRM Auto Populate Field From Option Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272262/crm-auto-populate-field-from-option-set).
2. [Auto Populate lookupfield](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/392630/auto-populate-lookup-field/1056447)
3. [Dynamics CRM auto populate lookup values from custom field](https://immersivecoder.com/2020/03/26/dynamics-crm-auto-populate-lookup-values-from-custom-field-part-1/)

the Code I am using is :

```
    var userSetting = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings;
    var currentUser = new Array();
    currentUser[0] = new Object();
    currentUser[0].id = userSetting.userId;
    currentUser[0].Name = userSetting.userName;
    currentUser[0].entityType = "systemuser";
    executionContext.getFormContext().getAttribute("student").setValue(currentUser);
```

Comment: Please provide your code or do anticipate no help on this question.

Answer (score 1):

First, retrieve logged in user settings with

`var userSettings = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings`

Now, you should have access to the ID, Name, and Type(systemuser) of the record you want to set in your lookup field.

```
var currentUser = new Array();
var currentUserObject = new Object();
currentUserObject.id = userSettings.userId;
currentUserObject.name = userSettings.userName;
currentUserObject.entityType = "systemuser"
currentUser[0] = currentUserObject;
formContext.getAttribute("fieldname").setValue(currentUser);
```

From [getGlobalContext.userSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-utility/getglobalcontext/usersettings)

Comment: thanks @JustDoIt I used almost the same of your code with some changes but the problem did not solve yet

Comment: you will need to be a bit more specific/detailed @Alloylo

Comment: It works but I should click on the Save button. thanks, @Just Do It

Comment: if its not saving its not a real issue, depending on your requirements you can just call a save event. @Alloylo